# Change email for all subscriptions at once

Tags: support, notifications, user-accounts, email, email-notification

I moved to a new email address and would like all of the StackExchange filter alerts I receive to go to that one. However, seeing as I have quite a few of these, it'd be a pain to set up by setting an email for each subscription separately.

Is there a way to set a different email address for all filter subscriptions at once?